# Does a Buddy Pokémon's mood level affect Adventure Sync?

Tags: pokemon-go

As of the latest update to Pokémon Go, while a buddy's mood is at the highest level, the distance needed to walk before finding a candy of the buddy's species will be reduced, making it easier to find candies if you pay attention to your buddy.

Does this also apply when Pokémon Go isn't running? That is to say, does a buddy's excitement level affect distance tracked with Adventure Sync as well? If so, does the buddy need to be excited while Pokémon Go isn't running, or after starting the game again?

Comment: This isn't worth an answer yet as I haven't tried what you asked (was actually thinking about the same thing last night), but I have noticed that the distance tracked is at your buddies walking pace.  I turned the app on and got my lotad excited and walked to work and he still isn't here...  I also did a team GO rocket battle when I got here which didn't count for the battle with your buddy, presumably because he was not in range of me when I did the battle.  The app keeps updating the distance every time I check but I still don't see him

Comment: I haven't tested fully, but after feeding my buddy and putting my phone away I went for a walk. At the end of the walk, I opened the app up again to check how much distance Adventure Sync had registered and found that I had gained walk distance toward the buddy task, which says it only tracks distance while the buddy is out walking with you. This would imply that the buddy is out and walking even if the app is closed.

Comment: I also tried what Kadima did this morning and experienced the same thing.  Unfortunately we won't know for sure how this applies to candy distance for awhile since buddy leveling seems like it will take a long time.  I got all 10 hearts yesterday and it barely made a dent in the 2nd friendship star (after I was already 4 stars into that one...)

Answer (score 0):

It is the other way around - Adventure Sync distance counts toward the "Walk together" hearts, so after walking for enough distance, your buddy will have enough energy to get "super excited" without a Poffin. It can happen if you give your buddy a berry and go on long several hour walk and cover enough distance. You might want to enter game before 3 hour mark to make sure the buddy is still "joining your adventure" when the synchronization for Adventure Sync actually happens and/or to feed it another berry.

In an excited state the distance to get candy and mega energy is reduced by half.